# Occasionally empty tableView using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `UITableViewController` with task items that is hooked to Core Data via `NSFetchedResultsController` using Apple's template for `CoreDataTableViewController` (subclass). The TVC opens detailViewController which handles edits and saves.

Sometimes when I have tasks saved in Core Data and EDIT one task and then save it, the detailViewController saves the data and makes back segue to the TVC, but the tableView shows no records at all, it's just empty. When I kill the app and run it again, all tasks appear as they should.

It is very rare behaviour and therefore hard to track and debug. Does anybody have any ideas what is causing the empty tableView in those rare cases?

**In DetailVC.m**

```
- (void)save
{
    if (self.editingTask) {
        [[DataManager sharedInstance] updateItem:self.editingTask withText:self.textField.text date:self.datePicker.date priority:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex completed:NO];
    } else {
        [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveNewItem:self.textField.text date:self.datePicker.date priority:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**In DataManager.m**

```
- (CoreDataStatus)updateItem:(Task *)editingTask withText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date priority:(NSUInteger)priority completed:(BOOL)completed
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    Task *taskToUpdate = editingTask;
    taskToUpdate.due = date;
    taskToUpdate.text = text;
    taskToUpdate.priority = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:priority];
    taskToUpdate.completed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:completed];

    // save
    NSError *error = nil;
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    if (!error) {

        [self updateNotificationsAndBadgeCount];
        return Success;
    } else {
        return Error;
    }
}
```

**In TVC.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Task"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completed = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"due" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
}
```

**In CoreDataTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)performFetch
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] performFetch: failed", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Show the code... Are you using Cache ? What logic did you add in your subclass ? Are you saving on same thread or on background thread ? Are you calling table refresh on main thread ?

Comment: Code added, no cache. I have included the relevant code for fetching and updating data. I did saves on background threads, but had some problems, so currently all fetches and saves go on the appDelegate's context on main thread. In TVC.m I call tableView reloadData on main thread in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Where are you calling performFetch: ? If you were to do that in viewDidAppear, your problem would probably go away. The above code seems to indicate you're not doing it at all.

Comment: And please, PLEASE, don't pull the managed object context from the application delegate. Pass it IN to the view controller - this is what Apple's template does.

Comment: @quellish In previous comment I say that I call [self.tableView reloadData] in TVC.m viewWillAppear and that triggers the CDTVC fetch.

Comment: Where is performFetch: though? reloadData does not itself perform a fetch. You are showing where you create the fetched results controller, but not where you call performFetch: on it. A fetched results controller will work without a performFetch:, but it can appear to misbehave because without performFetch: there is no initial state.

Comment: @quellish Added code for performFetch in CDTVC. So you say I should call performFetch on the CDTVC instead of reload data on the TVC?

Comment: You need to do both. The fetched results controller gets the data, the table view displays it.

Comment: Again, what is calling *your* performFetch? Just calling reloadData will cause the tableview to update itself, but it will not cause the fetched results controller to get data. It's likely that the places you are currently calling reloadData should instead be calling your performFetch

Comment: OK, I replaced the call and will test heavily. So far so good. Thanks.